# If $v$ is uniformly Lipschitz, is the solution $T$ of $\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}(t,x)=v(t,T_t(x))$ uniformly Lipschitz as well?

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, ordinary-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions

Let $\tau>0$, $d\in\mathbb N$, $v:[0,\tau]\times\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb R^d$ with $v\in C^{0,\:1}(\mathbb R^d,C^0([0,\tau],\mathbb R^d))$ and $T:[0,\tau]\times\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb R^d$ be continuously differentiable in the first argument with $$\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}(t,x)=v(t,T_t(x))\;\;\;\text{for all }(t,x)\in(0,\tau)\times\mathbb R^d\tag1$$ and $$T_0=\operatorname{id}_{\mathbb R^d}.\tag2$$

> Are we able to show that $T\in C^{0,\:1}(\mathbb R^d,C^1([0,\tau],\mathbb R^d))$, i.e. $$\max\left(\sup_{t\in[0,\:\tau]}\left\|T_t(x)-T_t(y)\right\|,\sup_{t\in[0,\:\tau]}\left\|\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}(t,x)-\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}(t,y)\right\|\right)\le c\left\|x-y\right\|\tag3$$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb R^d$ for some $c\ge0$?

Note that \begin{equation}\begin{split}\left\|T_t(x)-T_t(y)\right\|&=\left\|\int_0^tv(s,T_s(x))-v(s,T_s(y))\:{\rm d}s+x-y\right\|\\&\le\int_0^t\left\|v(s,T_s(x))-v(s,T_s(y))\right\|+\left\|x-y\right\|\end{split}\tag4\end{equation} for all $t\in[0,\tau]$ and $x,y\in\mathbb R^d$ and, if $c_1$ is the Lipschitz constant of $v$, $$\left\|v(s,T_s(x))-v(s,T_s(y))\right\|+\left\|x-y\right\|\le c_1\left\|T_s(x)-T_s(y)\right\|\tag5$$ for all $s\in[0,\tau]$ and $x,y\in\mathbb R^d$.

**EDIT**: The desired claim can be found in [Theorem 4.1 of *Shapes and Geometries: Metrics, Analysis, Differential Calculus, and Optimization, Second Edition*](https://books.google.com/books?id=V773JJZd6RMC&pg=PA180&lpg=PA180&dq=%22Equivalence+between+Velocities+and+Transformations%22+%22theorem+4.1%22&source=bl&ots=MwpBSf7FNe&sig=ACfU3U2PQkAPtdP--lqKR3uL1cmzSVONlw&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiks-Xlg9TqAhUoNOwKHdNtA-cQ6AEwAXoECAsQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Equivalence%20between%20Velocities%20and%20Transformations%22%20%22theorem%204.1%22&f=false):
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is $T(t,x)$ a vector or an operator? I ask because I see $T_0(x) = \mathrm{id}_{\mathbb R^d}$, which is not coherent with the definition of $T$.

Comment: @LL3.14 It is a vector, but I denote $T_t(x):=T(t,x)$. Sorry, I see where the confusion comes from. The $x$ shouldn't be there in $(2)$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I'm sorry, the right-hand side was supposed to be $v(t,T_t(x))$ not $v(t,x)$. With the previous differential equation, it is trivial to show the claim. Please take note of my edit. Unfortunately, there is no proof of (T1) in the book; they just claim that it follows "by standard arguments".

Comment: The cited text plays fast and loose with the notation, but in general it is preferred to denote the same object with the same notation inside a formula, that is, either all $T_t(x)$ or all $T(t,x)$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Yeah, I think the notation in the book is a mess, but it seems like this is the "standard reference" for shape optimization (but I'd be happy if someone knows a better one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to treat the two parts of the integral formula separately to get
$$
\|T_t(x)-T_t(y)\|\le\|x-y\|+c\int_0^t\|T_s(x)-T_s(y)\|\,ds
$$
This now is the standard situation for the Grönwall lemma giving
$$
\|T_t(x)-T_t(y)\|\le e^{ct}\|x-y\|
$$
so that the claim is true with $c_1=e^{c\tau}$.

That the exponential in the new Lipschitz constant can not be avoided shows the standard example of the vector field $v(t,x)=cx$ where then $T_t(x)=xe^{ct}$.

---

Insertion of that result then shows that
$$
\|\partial_tT_t(x)-\partial_tT_t(y)\|
=\|v(t,T_t(x))-v(t,T_t(y))
\le c\|T_t(x)-T_t(y)\|\le ce^{ct}\|x-y\|
$$